# Bootbox and css class : z-index weird behaviour

Tags: css, angular, bootbox

I have set a css class :

```
.on-top-bootbox-alert-2 {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

But when I inspect the code in Chrome developer view, I am getting the html :

[image]
and the css:

[image]

I don't understand why the value of z-index differs from the class defined in the main.css.

The angular source is :

```
bootbox.confirm({
                message: "Confirmez-vous l'envoi de la demande de CRA ?",
                backdrop: false,
                className: "on-top-bootbox-alert-2",
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'Oui',
                        className: 'btn-success'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'Non',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you change this recently?

Comment: what do you mean? no, I didn't change my post

Comment: haha, Did you change the value from 7 to 9999 in your main.css recently?

Comment: No, I didn't, I don't think it's a cache issue. the strange thing is that it works on local, but not on the server.

Comment: Try `!important` in your css to see if its not being overridden by javascript

Comment: I am getting z-index  : 7!important